# how to setup receiverEmail with paypal-iOS-SDK 2.12.9

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm new in using paypal-iOS-SDK. I want to test my app about the payment part. I use paypal SDK as the payment platform.My code like this:

```
// Create a PayPalPaymentViewController.
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfiguration delegate:self];
```

And I check the PayPalConfiguration class.I didn't find any property to setup the receiverEmail. I check out some old document.And find the code like this:

```
    // Create a PayPalPaymentViewController with the credentials and payerId, the PayPalPayment
  // from the previous step, and a PayPalPaymentDelegate to handle the results.
  PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
  paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:@"YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
                                                                  receiverEmail:@"YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
                                                                        payerId:aPayerId
                                                                        payment:payment
                                                                       delegate:self];
```

who can tell me how to setup the receiverEmail for receive payment using the latest paypal-iOS-SDK(2.12.9).Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set a receiverEmail in the 2.x versions of the mSDK. Instead, you should set your client ID as documented in the SDK. You can get a client ID by going to the [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) dashboard portal site and creating an application if you have not already done so.

The client ID is tied to the business account which will receive the payments. Be sure to use the right client ID for each environment (e.g. sandbox vs. live/production).